# How do I get a variable from one function into another?

Tags: c++, function

Exactly like the title says, how can I get my disc variable from my discr function into my calcRoots function?

```
// Function calculating roots
bool calcRoots(double coeffs[], int coeffLength, double roots[], int rootLength) {
   if(disc >= 0) {
      roots[rootLength - 1] = ((-(coeffs[coeffLength - 2]) + sqrt(disc)) / (2*(coeffs[coeffLength - coeffLength])));
      roots[rootLength - rootLength] = ((-(coeffs[coeffLength - 2]) - sqrt(disc)) / (2*(coeffs[coeffLength - coeffLength])));
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}

// Solves the discriminant
double discr(double coeffs[], int coeffLength){
   double disc = (pow(coeffs[coeffLength - 2],2)-4*coeffs[coeffLength - coeffLength]*coeffs[coeffLength - 1]);
   return disc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention nay language but i supose to be C++.
Inside calcRoots you can make a call to discr and get the value to a variable like this:

```
double disc = discr(coeffs[], coeffLength);
```

Then use the value store in the variable. Hope this help.

Comment: Yes it is C++, my apologies. That worked perfectly! Thank you very much! Also, when calling an array you don't need the []. So:

double disc = discr(coeffs, coeffLength);

is what I used and it works!

Comment: Great! remember to mark the answer as the correct one!